# Auto assign author to new posts with wp_insert_post_data

Tags: author

I need to make the default author for all **new posts** be already selected but leave existing posts unmodified.

So since the default post status is "draft" i thought to only do this if the post is a draft like so:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'update_author', '99', 2 );

function update_author($data , $postarr) {
if ($postarr['post_status'] == 'draft') {
    $data['post_author'] = 45;
 }
  return $data;
}
```

But then it never runs, so i tried the other way around. Do it when it isn't "published" but then it runs for all new and existing posts...

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'update_author', '99', 2 );

function update_author($data , $postarr) {      
 if ($postarr['post_status'] != 'published') {       
    $data['post_author'] = 45;
 }
  return $data;
}
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to know if it's a new post, you juste need to read the value of `$postarr["ID"]` :

```
$postType = "post";

add_filter("wp_insert_post_data" . $postType, function ($data, $postarr) {

    if (0 === $postarr["ID"]) { // it's a new post

        $data["post_author"] = 45;

    }


    return $data;


}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Wow i never seen that way of adding a filter.

Comment: I juste have seen I forgot the first line `$postType = "post";`, I have edited the code. look here for details about anonymous functions http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: The check works! Thanks for so much sorry for so little.